# SQL query SET & Update but not being called from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update table rows to have random numbers. Now I can achieve this using phpMyAdmin and run it via SQL query. However if I try and run the same code via a PHP call then it doesn't work. 
Any ideas why this would be the case and how I would correct it?

*Table* name is: **num_image**

*Column* Name: **rownum**

This is the SQL I'm using:

```
SET @rownum := 0; 
UPDATE num_image SET rownum = (@rownum:=@rownum+1) ORDER BY RAND();
```

I've tried entering it in my php code as follows:

```
<?php
  // Connect to database
  include 'DB.php';
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  // Assigns a new random number with no duplicates to database for each rownum row.

  $updaterownum = mysql_query("SET @rownum := 0; UPDATE num_image SET rownum = (@rownum:=@rownum+1) ORDER BY RAND();");

  echo 'All rownums have been updated!';

?>
```

*My database connection works fine as I use the same for other database updates and inserts. So I've narrowed it down to how I'm inserting the actual SQL in my PHP call and believe I have to edit the way I call it?*

I'm sure it's something minor I have missed, though I'm stumped. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You execute two SQL queries in one query call. That cannot be done. You also should not use the mysql extension, it is deprecated. it says so in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @KIKO Software : The server I'm using only has 5.6.39 so I have to work with what I have at the moment. Thanks for the direction in regards to two SQl queries in one query call though.

Comment: Please use `<?php phpinfo();` to verify which MySQL API's your version has, or read: [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware mysqlnd 5.0.10 lol! Yes I need to update, though considering my site is built on this I'll have to finish my project (personal project) then will rebuild on the latest. Time is the issue, or else I would just stop now and rebuild ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following polished code can do the job in PHP. However, as mentioned in comments; The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future.

```
<?php
  // Connect to database
  include 'DB.php';
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
  if($con)
  {
        $updaterownum = mysql_query("SET @rownum := 0");
        $updaterownum = mysql_query("UPDATE num_image SET rownum = (@rownum:=@rownum+1) ORDER BY RAND()");
        if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)
        {
            echo 'All rownums have been updated!';
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Nothing changed after running update query!";
        }
  }
  else
  {
      echo "Not able to connect";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I needed and works the treat. I know it's best to update to mysqli though at current time doesn't permit and that's something I'll have to do in the future. Cheers for working with my current limitations I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I see a document at: 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Here are some brief lines:

MySQL optionally allows having multiple statements in one statement string. Sending multiple statements at once reduces client-server round trips but requires special handling.

Multiple statements or multi queries must be executed with mysqli_multi_query(). The individual statements of the statement string are separated by semicolon. Then, all result sets returned by the executed statements must be fetched.

The MySQL server allows having statements that do return result sets and statements that do not return result sets in one multiple statement.

Comment: Thanks for the info :-) when I update to the current mysql then I'll implement this.